# Place WebView inside ScrollView in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webview, scrollview

I'd like to place partial WebView(not full screen) on ScrollView(UGUI component), so WebView can be scrolled with other components on ScrollView.

As a newbie of Unity, I though it might work if I put WebView as child of WebView, but wouldn't.

I used https://github.com/gree/unity-webview for WebView and located it under Content as below.

[image]
[image]

And the WebView is just floating on the screen.

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this in Unity?